# Is using an If[] condition faster than KronckerDelta[]?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, evaluation, conditional

I have a code which has a term in a summation like:

```
KroneckerDelta[M,0]*func[M]
```

where `func[M]` is a time consuming numerical integral with a parameter `M`. I am looping over different values of `M`.

My question is, does Mathematica evaluate `func[M]` even if the `KroneckerDelta[M,0]` evaluates to  `0` (i.e. when `M != 0`)? Or does it recognize that since the `KroneckerDelta[M,0]` is giving `0`, so the product must be zero and hence doesn't actually evaluate the `func[M]` part then?

Because if it is evaluating the time consuming numerical integral in `func[M]` anyway, I feel using an `If[M=0]` like statement would save computation time...? Right?

Thanks.

Comment: This `Table[KroneckerDelta[1, M] Pause[M], {M, 1, 3}] // AbsoluteTiming` takes six seconds.

Comment: To clarify: `Times` in Mathematica does not short-circuit multiplication by zero. Indeed, it cannot since `Times` has no `HoldAll` attribute. This means that all it's arguments must be evaluated before `Times` does anything at all. Compare this with `And` and `Or`, which DO have the the `HoldAll` attribute and will short-circuit the moment they encounter `False` / `True` respectively.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Gotcha. Thanks. Makes sense.
Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find out easily enough:

```
func[x_] := Pause[1];
Table[KroneckerDelta[M, 0]*func[M], {M, 0, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
Table[If[M == 0, func[M]], {M, 0, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The first one takes 11 seconds, the second one takes 1 second. So in the one with the KroneckerDelta, it is evaluating the func for each value of M whereas the If[ ] construct only evaluates the func when M=0.

Comment: Can you clarify what happens as it gets larger?

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response. I guess, then a general rule would be to use If[] over KroneckerDelta[] for numerical computations....?

Comment: @odomosis -- I would imagine that it depends on context, but yes, in this case you are wasting computation to compute things that you know are going to eventually be multiplied by zero!